# R function that return a vector with position occurence of each value?

Tags: r, performance, vector, position, find-occurrences

I am searching for a function that return a vector with the position/count of each value of a vector.

Here an example :

I have :

```
vec<-c("A","A","A","B","B","C")
```

I want :

```
c(1,2,3,1,2,1)
```

I have created a function that works but I am looking for a faster way to get it, as I have a big dataset.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `sequence(rle(vec)$lengths)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use `ave` in base R :

```
vec<-c("A","A","A","B","B","C")
result <- as.integer(ave(vec, vec, FUN = seq_along))
result
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rowid(vec)
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 1
```